# Split string with two brackets

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a string that comes out like this:

```
String line = "2022{yyyy}{mm}{dd}";
```

I want to split it into an arraylist like this:

```
2022
yyyy
mm
dd
```

how can i do this?

Comment: When you split, you get a string array. Why do you need an array list? Are you sure about the type of the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

```java
String line = "2022{yyyy}{mm}{dd}";
String[] parts = line.split("[{}]+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));  // [2022, yyyy, mm, dd]
```

Another possibility might be to do a regex find all on `\w+` using a formal pattern matcher.

Comment: thank you very much! and do you know how to split it out this: [2022, {yyyy}, {mm}, {dd}]

Comment: Yes, split on `(?=\{)`

Answer (score 1):

Here would be an example approach if you wanted to use four capturing groups:

- [`(\d{4}){(y{4})}{(m{2})}{(d{2})}`](https://regex101.com/r/O59FiG/1)

[image]

Having said that, Tim's approach is much simpler and I'd go for that.